# How to configure hibernate jpa to work with mysql ndb(cluster)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mysql-cluster

I want to use Hibernate JPA with MySql NDB cluster.

- Does Hibernate-JPA support MySql NDB?
- I found this document on using OpenJPA/ClusterJPA with NDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/ndbapi/en/mccj-using-jpa.html. Could someone point me to a doc similar to this using Hibernate JPA and MySql NDB.

Answer (score 0):

I used a wrong port to connect to NDB (1186).  After I corrected the port (3306) it all worked fine.

Comment: Could you share with me how you got this working? I can't figure out how to specify the engine for Hibernate 4.3.  Is there a special Hibernate property to specify NDBCLUSTER?

Comment: @ram me too want to know how you got this working? Please Post some more explanation...

Comment: @Thangadurai I did this few years back.  I don't remember details now :(